# What to do with interesting questions for which you have an answer?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I ask a question I know the answer to?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to)

A few hours ago I was stuck with an IE9 CSS problem. I normally try to first find a solution myself and if that fails, check for an existing question at SO. If there isn't one, I post it as a question.

However, this time I found the answer myself before having to access SO. I think the answer was interesting to share with the community, but it would feel silly to ask a question and immediately answer it myself.

What would be the policy/guideline in such situations?

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate after providing an answer even though I knew your question had been asked before. Your question is perfectly valid, though I stress searching for duplicates prior to answering your own question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

If it is indeed interesting, ask the question and answer it, provided that no duplicate exists. From the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> Please look around to see if your
>   question has already been asked (and
>   maybe even answered!) before you ask.
>   It’s also perfectly fine to ask and
>   answer your own question, as long as
>   you pretend you’re on Jeopardy: phrase
>   it in the form of a question.

If your question (and subsequent answer) will help people find a solution to their problem, by all means, don't hesitate. Just ensure that you aren't posting a duplicate.

Comment: I just asked this same question, not realizing it had been asked before.  I had already looked in the FAQ and didn't see the answer.  Turns out it requires clicking "read more" to see the remainder of that FAQ -- which is only an additional two sentences!  If this comes up a lot, I'd propose making the entire FAQ visible so newbies like me can see it off the bat.